# How to forbid create Object via reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

### Prologue

I have a class :

```
public final class Session {

    private int userId;
    private String token;

    Session(int userId, String token) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
}
```

As you see, we can create object via reflection.

- I know that i can forbid access to constructor via **`private`** or **`package-private`** modificators.

### The goals

- Forbid creating of object even via reflection way to preserve security.
- Make access to fill object fields only **`package-private`**.

> P.S. Maybe it can be complete via **OOP/OOD** way?

Comment: I'm just curious as to know why you want to do this unless you expect code to be injected into your application.

Comment: @cricket_007 it just my curiosity. In our century security is a most important thing. This my point of view.

Comment: I agree security is important, but I think if anyone can decompile your app, then you have bigger problems then them modifying your objects at runtime via reflection.

Comment: @cricket_007 just let imagine.  If someone getting a pieces of your sources, he can call directly constructor if he knows a `packageName` and `className`.

Comment: It's not nearly as big of an issue as you imagine it is. It's also not possible to do what you described, no matter how much of your source code he has.

Comment: @Kayaman, maybe. It just my curiosity.

Comment: You could test your theory. Try to access some other application's classes with reflection and see what happens.

Comment: I may be wrong, but you would need to modify the classpath to import those classes if you could instantiate them like that.

Comment: You can forbid access to methods via reflection with the `final` modifier? Very interesting.

Comment: @Holger yes, you are right. My mistake. Take my apologies.

Comment: Reflection isn't your only threat vector. Unless you seal your package, anybody can instantiate your class with ordinary Java code.

Answer (score 1):

On plain Java, install a [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) with a policy describing what you want.

While Android has a SecurityManager class, the docs say not to use it, and I don't think there's any way to do what you want, although I'm also not sure how it makes sense.

Comment: For Java - i think it's OK. How about Android?

Comment: Upd. From docs : `...It allows an application to determine, before performing a possibly unsafe or sensitive operation...`. So it's not exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: @ssh Sorry, missed the Android tag, will update my answer, although, I don't think it's possible on Android. Also, on your second comment, I'm not sure why that quote suggests it's not what you want. You consider various types of access via reflection sensitive, so want to disallow them. That's exactly what a SecurityManager is for.

Comment: @ssh - You should be able to import `SecurityManager` in Android, it's part of the Standard Java SDK.